Scalar Multiplication vs Homogeneity
What is the difference between closure under scalar multiplication and homogeneity - can they be used interchangeable when discussing linear transformations?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

When do you call a map "closed under scalar multiplication"?

Take a look at this question as well that makes the difference between homogenity as a generalization of "closure under scalar multiplication" more explicit.

Homogeneity is a more general concept than closure under scalar multiplication. For single argument linear transforms these are one and the same but in general they are not
For example a linear transformation $A$ is called closed under scalar multiplication / homogenous of degree 1 if:
$$ A(cx) = cA(x) $$
But we can have more general flavors of homogeneity. For example perhaps if our transformation $A$ is quadratic homogenous then:
$$ A(cx) = c^2 A(x) $$
Or for example if we have a multivariable transformation $A(x,y)$ for example $A(x,y) = x+y$  we might say $A$ is homogenous of degree 1 because
$$ A(cx,cy) = cA(x,y) $$
This concept of Homogeneity as we can see is very flexible and general. The reason you are being taught both at once is because "closure under scalar multiplication" is easy to understand and this easy concept is being used as a bridge to understand the subtler and more complicated concept of "homogenous of degree n" by stating "linear maps are homogenous of degree 1".
